# Bad URI (is not URI?) LinkThumbnailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in Rails and developing a small app using LinkThumbnailer. I am trying to get the URL from user input and pass the URL to LinkThumbnailer but it's not working. I am getting bad URI(is not URI?) error.

When I pass

```
def index
  @links = LinkThumbnailer.generate("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
end
```

It works fine but when I pass

```
def index
  @links = Link.new(params[:weblink])
  @links = LinkThumbnailer.generate(@links)
end
```

I am getting a error

```
URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): #<Link::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f9577b97328>):
```

Please help me to fix this. What i want to do is to get the URL from the User and convert it by LinkThumbnailer and save the Title, Description, Favicon and Image to database.

Comment: What does `Link.sorted` return? Please show us the code of the `LinkThumbnailer.generate` method.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, its not the link.sorted its LinkThumbnailer.generate("http:www.stackoverflow.com")

Comment: I tried in rails console its working.

Comment: LinkThumbnailer.generate('a.weblink') it generates the outputs in console.

Comment: `LinkThumbnailer.generate` obviously expects a string (the URL) argument, not an complex model. Therefore it can't extract the URL from your instance of a `Link`. How does `params[:weblink]` look like? Or does your `@links` object have a method that might return the URL as a string?

Comment: Could you please suggest an example for me.

Comment: Sorry, I can't suggest without you answering my questions first. Perhaps it is `LinkThumbnailer.generate(params[:weblink])`, but that is just without knowing how your `params` look like

Comment: I have a form in vew template and the input filed type for url is :weblink.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
def index
  @links = LinkThumbnailer.generate(params[:weblink])
end
```

Comment: Is it exactly the same error than before? What URL do you use to test, did you test that it is a valid URL?

Comment: You will need to use full, valid URLs like: `http://www.google.com` or `http://www.youtube.com`.

Comment: its not working though. I saved the url complete URL lists in db also. And tried to pass the UrLs, still I am getting the same error. Its working in console. I have used the valid urls.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should do it from model.

```
  class link < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :link_title
  after_create :link_favicon
  after_create :link_description
  after_create :link_image

  def link_title
    #check if it's a URL
    if link[0..6] == 'http://' || link[0..7] == 'https://'
      begin
      preview = LinkThumbnailer.generate(weblink)
      preview.title
      rescue LinkThumbnailer::Exceptions => e
      preview = 'No title'
      end
    end
  end
  def link_favicon
    #check if it's a URL
    if link[0..6] == 'http://' || link[0..7] == 'https://'
      begin
      preview = LinkThumbnailer.generate(weblink)
      preview.favicon
      rescue LinkThumbnailer::Exceptions => e
      preview = 'http://image/url/jpg'
      end
    end
  end
  def link_description
    #check if it's a URL
    if link[0..6] == 'http://' || link[0..7] == 'https://'
      begin
      preview = LinkThumbnailer.generate(weblink)
      preview.description
      rescue LinkThumbnailer::Exceptions => e
      preview = 'No title'
      end
    end
  end
  def link_favicon
    #check if it's a URL
    if link[0..6] == 'http://' || link[0..7] == 'https://'
      begin
      preview = LinkThumbnailer.generate(weblink)
      preview.image
      rescue LinkThumbnailer::Exceptions => e
      preview = 'http://image/url/jpg'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

2. then in controller

```
def index
  @links = Link.all
end
```

3. in view

```
<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <%= link.title %>
  <%= link.favicon %>
  <%= link.description %>
  <%= link.image %>
<%end %>
```